# Scaling multiple axes in PlotChart

Tags: actionscript, flex4, charts

When I programmatically create a PlotChart starting w/ no series and adding series w/ own scaling and verticalAxes (and Renderers but not necessary for behavior error), the axes and data show, but the default axis controls all scaling and the other axes are erroneous. Thus, the yValue magnitudes do not correspond to their associated axes and mixing series w/ grossly different orders of magnitude squishes all but the largest into indistinguishable floor values. I cannot null out the default vertical axis as it gets an null pointer error. [Click anywhere on the chart to add the next series.]

```
package
{
/*
* Attempt to dynamically create graph w/ varying series. Having difficulty getting axis to render correctly based
* on sets of series. Having trouble getting more than one series. I can't munge the yValue property because in my
* actual code all of the data elements are instances of the same class with properties akin to series, xValue, and yValue.
*
*/
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import mx.charts.AxisRenderer;
import mx.charts.DateTimeAxis;
import mx.charts.LinearAxis;
import mx.charts.PlotChart;
import mx.charts.chartClasses.Series;
import mx.charts.events.ChartEvent;
import mx.charts.series.PlotSeries;
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

public class GraphSample extends PlotChart
{
    public function GraphSample()
    {
        super();
        this.selectionMode = "single";
        this.percentWidth = 80;
        this.series = new Array();
        this.verticalAxisRenderers = new Array();
        this.showDataTips = true;
    }

    protected override function createChildren():void {
        super.createChildren();

        // Create the horizontal axis
        var hAxis:DateTimeAxis = new DateTimeAxis();
        hAxis.dataUnits = "days";
        this.horizontalAxis = hAxis; 

        // NOTE: I do not want an automatically created verticalAxis, but can't seem to avoid it
                    // Add vertical axis renderer
        var axis:AxisRenderer = new AxisRenderer();
        axis.axis = this.verticalAxis;
        axis.horizontal = false;
        axis.setStyle("showLabels", true);
        axis.setStyle("showLine", true);
        this.verticalAxisRenderers.push(axis);
        this.verticalAxisRenderers = this.verticalAxisRenderers;

        this.addEventListener(ChartEvent.CHART_CLICK, addSeries);
    }

    private var seriesColors:Array = [0x888888, 0xFFC833, 0xFF6433, 0xE73399, 
        0x8133CC, 0x346B9B, 0x33C399, 0x98F133];
    private var seriesColorCursor:int = 0;

    private const ONE_DAY:Number = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    private const TODAY:Date = new Date();

    private function addSeries(event:MouseEvent):void {
        var dimension:Object = newDimension();

        var series:Series = new PlotSeries(); 
        series.displayName = dimension.name;
        series.dataFunction = genericFieldRetriever;
        series.setStyle("fill", seriesColors[seriesColorCursor++]);
        if (seriesColorCursor > seriesColors.length) seriesColorCursor %= seriesColors.length;

        series.dataProvider = dimension.elements;
        this.series.push(series);


        var seriesAxis:LinearAxis = new LinearAxis();
        series.setAxis("verticalAxis", seriesAxis);
        var min:Number = Number.MAX_VALUE, max:Number = 0;
        for each (var ele:Object in series.dataProvider) {
            if (ele.value > max) max = ele.value;
            if (ele.value < min) min = ele.value;
        }
        seriesAxis.minimum = min * 0.85;
        seriesAxis.maximum = max * 1.2;
        seriesAxis.displayName = series.displayName;
        seriesAxis.title = series.displayName;

        // Add vertical axis renderer
        var axis:AxisRenderer = new AxisRenderer();
        axis.axis = seriesAxis;
        axis.horizontal = false;
        axis.setStyle("color", series.getStyle("fill"));
        axis.setStyle("showLabels", true);
        axis.setStyle("showLine", true);
        this.verticalAxisRenderers.push(axis);
        this.verticalAxisRenderers = this.verticalAxisRenderers;
        // also strokes?



        // http://www.flexdeveloper.eu/forums/flex-charting/creating-linecolumn-series-dynamically/
        this.series = this.series;
        this.invalidateSeriesStyles();

        if (names.length == 0) this.removeEventListener(ChartEvent.CHART_CLICK, addSeries);
    }

    /**
     * A fake of the server data retrieval mechanism. 
     * @return wrapper w/ name and elements set where each element has a data and value.
     */
    private function newDimension():Object {
        var result:Object = new Object();
        result['name'] = names.shift();
        var elements:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        var thisBase:int = base.shift();
        var thisMax:int = maxAdd.shift();
        for (var date:Date = new Date(TODAY.getTime() - 10 * ONE_DAY); date.getTime() <= TODAY.getTime(); date = new Date(date.getTime() + ONE_DAY)) {
            var element:Object = new Object();
            element['date'] = date;
            element['value'] = thisBase + Math.random() * thisMax;
            elements.addItem(element);
        }
        result['elements'] = elements;
        return result;
    }
    private var names:Array = ['fat', 'carbs', 'steps', 'walking miles', 'pounds', 'cycling miles', 'running miles', 'skiing hours', 'lifting mins'];
    private var base:Array = [0, 20, 1000, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    private var maxAdd:Array = [100, 200, 9000, 4, 200, 40, 8, 3, 75];


    private function genericFieldRetriever(series:Series, item:Object, fieldName:String):Object {
          if(fieldName == 'yValue')
              return(item.value);
          else if(fieldName == "xValue")
              return(item.date);
          else
              return null;
    }     

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the line

```
 series.setAxis("verticalAxis", seriesAxis);
```

That is not equivalent to

```
series.verticalAxis = seriesAxis;
```

Once I changed that, everything works perfectly, but it cannot handle the abstract Series class b/c that class does not have the setter for verticalAxis.